# Allow or Restrict Specific Tetant's user in MultiTenant application in Azure AD

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, multi-tenant

I have created one multi-tenant application in Azure and I want only user of same tenant and one specific tenant's(my other directory) user can login and not any other user should login. Any setting to restrict or allow specific users setting.

Comment: Check the `tid` claim to see if it's the tenant id you expected. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52682803/restrict-azure-active-directory-app-access-to-specific-tenants?answertab=votes#tab-top.

Comment: If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, there is currently no such feature. Controlling access will need to be done in the process of authorizing users. You cannot prevent users from agreeing to log in to your multi-tenant application.

What you can do is build this capability into your application - the auth/JWT token contains the tenantID (tid) as a claim. You can authorize access only for known tenants in your app's allow list.  see:[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29132207/azure-active-directory-multi-tenant-application).

You can submit your [suggestions](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/34192--general-feedback) to Microsoft and then vote on the feature.

Answer (score -2):

It is not possible to put such restriction in Azure AD.

You have to check the `issuer` (`iss`) or `tid` claim in the commig token to restrict tenants in your app directly. No other way to achieve that.

Please refer this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/tenant-restrictions#configuration)

Comment: I don't see how you link is relevant. it talks about blocking an organization from accessing certain tenants, not tenants accessing an app.